# Android Service to watch for foreground app changes?

Tags: android

I have a utility app that changes the screen (much like a night screen type app) and I wanted to add a whitelist to bypass the night light when certain apps are in use.

I have found how to view what the current foreground app is but I dont know how to tell when the foreground app changes, aside from checking every 5 seconds which I dont want to do as it would be quite heavy.

Is there any way with a foreground service to monitor foreground app changes?

Comment: "I have found how to view what the current foreground app is" -- this is not possible on modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons, unless there is some new security flaw floating around.

Comment: @CommonsWare you can do it with usage stats and looking for the last app to have had the Move_to_foreground event, unless that has changed with android P?

Comment: I would not assume that those results are updated in real time, across several versions of Android and thousands of device models.